# Efficient Approach: JSON File Write or File Append

Tags: java, json, file

Which approach is more efficient

1) Append few json objects in a file

2) Clear file and rewrite json

JSON Structure

`{
"Regex":[],
"Entity": {"":"","":"","":""}
}`

Here,I want to append some new entries in Entity.

Answer (score 1):

Appending is much efficient, as the system is aware of the position. Whole file rewriting will take more time. Go with appending,